# Lpush and Zadd methods of Jedis not found in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jedis

I have written a beanshell sampler which has the objective of setting the multiple values for a single key. I tried with lpush just for the start. Then I went on using the zadd method which I believe is for adding multiple values for a single key.

But, in both the cases, I am getting an error in the log viewer that the respective method in the jedis class does not exist. How do I go about resolving this error.

I have tried to replace the jedis jar file(current version i am using is: 2.2.1) with the latest version(in the lib folder) in order to ensure the completeness of the methods to be used. But then, while starting the jmeter from command line throws java.lang.VerifyError.

Please let me know the solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Show your code so that we can help more precisely.

Another option is to use this if you only want to read the values:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RedisDataSet/